# Why do we need to pass response and request object in forrward method of RequestDispatcher

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

```
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet{   
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response {   
      RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("SecondServlet");    
      rd.forward(request,response);
  }
}
```

Now it make sense to me passing request object to SecondServlet i.e. if a client request to do something then the *request* forwarded. But what is the point of passing the response object of FirstServlet to SecondServlet?

Answer (score 0):

You can write any process to the second servlet It is not only html or jsp file
For example
On the second servlet you can write hello world in the response

Comment: But for that I can simply define hello world in the second servlet but what's the point to pass the object of response in FirstServlet to SecondServlet?

Comment: That is related to the business and abstraction example: suppose you have rules regarding to some data if a forward to aservlet if b forward to bservlet then forward to bservlet and in each servlet making some business for each one. However I don't use forward or include in this business tier separation and use it only to forward it to jsp